# Front End Plugin API for Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

TalkerApp has a very interesting feature, users can create little javascript extensions that allow them to [extend chat](https://talker.tenderapp.com/kb/api/frontend-plugin-api).

This would allow for stuff like extended oneboxing, syntax highlighting, sys tray notifications, keyboard shortcuts and so on.

As it stands users have already started extending chat with [user scripts](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts), the trouble though is that this is not that accessible as it requires a per machine, involved setup.

Could we build a simple extension mechanism where users can submit scripts to a central repo, and end-users select which scripts they want to run?

Comment: Everyone loves plugins and extensions

Comment: The setup is not really involved tho...

Comment: @drchenstern, for chorme it is not *that* bad ... however keeping the script up to date requires manual intervention

Answer (score 3):

*Personally*, my thoughts here are that this adds a few overheads that *currently* are non-issues because it is understood that the user-scripts are independent etc:

- there is an implicit expectation that we wouldn't break the API (keep in mind that at this point there *is* no formal API - only that-which-users-have-reverse-engineered-and-hacked-together); historically we have made some fairly large changes to the internals. OK, this is *less* likely now that it is pretty stable, but...
- it seems to formally legitimise the scripts; but these scripts have not been reviewed to check that they aren't doing anything silly - leaking horribly, or (for example) posting your security cookies somewhere. I'm not saying they *are* - but I wouldn't want to *blindly* open our users up to that (especially if somebody new posts a "new c001 script, try it!"
- fair enough, some of the user-script features are niche (highly valued by a small set of users, but not necessarily appropriate for the full audience); but where something *does* have wider value I'd rather see that it gets evaluated for addition to the core app
- when multiple additional scripts are thrown into the mix, you get even more interesting support scenarios - does X need Y but conflict with Z? I have no plan on managing that...

Re the specific points raised:

- syntax highlighting is something we intentionally didn't enable - *somewhere* there is a line between discussion and Q&A, and chat isn't *necessarily* the best home for everything
- desktop notifications is something we have discussed for consideration (in fact, I have an experimental hack in the code *right now*)
- extended oneboxing - isn't very extended if only people with the right script/combination-of-scripts see it...

Comment: I love the new desktop notifications :)