# Is there a way to programmatically get info about chats?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, api

I'm beginning some research into bots on the StackExchange platform, and I was wondering if there was a (reliable) way to get information about a chat, particularly a list of Room Owners for any given public-facing chat.

Ideally, this would be in a machine-readable format in such a way that would allow me to have to avoid scraping the Access tab of my bot's assigned chatroom.

As such, is there a JSON (or similar) endpoint where I can get this and other metadata about chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can see from [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) that there are no provisions for chat.

You can go to Stack Apps and upvote [this feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/1798/will-the-api-support-the-chat-system), but it has been **deferred since November 2010.**

But before that, [chat API access was declined by Jeff Atwood in July 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57040/will-chat-be-accessible-through-the-api).

Related:

- [Provide a streaming chat API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64252/provide-a-streaming-chat-api)
- [Front End Plugin API for Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73409/front-end-plugin-api-for-chat)

---

---

PS: So far have not uncovered any likely JSON `GET`s that the chat pages themselves use for this, either. And the chat directory pages load basic room info even when AJAX/JS is turned off. (Scraping may be your only recourse.)